I want to find out which IDs have both visit 2 and visit 4, e.g. My dataset looks like the following and the excel I have available is from 2015
I want to find out which IDs have both visit 2 and visit 4, e.g.  My dataset looks like the following and the excel I have available is from 2015.This is an example of how my dataset looks:



ID
Visit
unique id
Variable




101
2
101-v2
1234


101
3
101-v3
1234


102
2
102-v2
1234


102
4
102-v4
12234


103
2
103-v2
12234


103
3
103-v3
1234


103
4
103-v4
12234



I tried the following:
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A:A, 101, B:B,2)\>0,COUNTAIFS(A:A,"ID",B:B,4)\>0) "yes","no")
The formula didnt work at all...
After this i want to remove all the IDs that did not have paired values of visit 2 and 4..

What is the formula returning? #error, #value,... ? I'm also not sure what \ is doing in your formula.

COUNTIFS as entered for the whole range B:B would give a single value, not a row by row count. Also removing the backslash (\\) may get the your formula working.

It may be easier if you use table I think:
Overview of Excel tables - Microsoft Support

Insert a table for your data (select the range and choose Insert > Table)
Use filter button to add your conditions
Copy the data after filtering



=AND(1-ISNA(MATCH(A2&"-v"&{2,4},$C$2:$C$8,0)))
Or using table references: =AND(1-ISNA(MATCH([@ID]&"-v"&{2,4},[unique id],0)))
(Unsure if it requires being entered with ctrl+shift+enter)
